# web socket for chat not connecting - 404

Tags: javascript

I have used aws instance and used putty for deployment.Every thing is working well on my aws_ip:port .In this i have created a chat engine which is running on different port .This is created using webSocket .When i run my url on browser everything works file but websocket is not working. 8000 is the port of main server and 5000 is the port used forchat engine.it gives errror in console:"GET http://192.165.11.12:8000/undefined net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
""

i changed my localhost to

```
this.socket = io.connect('http://192.165.11.12:5000');

class ChatEngine{
  constructor(chatBoxId, userEmail){
    this.chatBox = $(`#${chatBoxId}`);
    this.userEmail = userEmail;

    this.socket = io.connect('http://192.165.11.12:5000');

    if (this.userEmail){
        this.connectionHandler();
    }

}


connectionHandler(){
    let self = this;

    this.socket.on('connect', function(){
        console.log('connection established using sockets...!');


        self.socket.emit('join_room', {
            user_email: self.userEmail,
            chatroom: 'codeial'
        });

        self.socket.on('user_joined', function(data){
            console.log('a user joined!', data);
        })


    });

    // CHANGE :: send a message on clicking the send message button
    $('#send-message').click(function(){
        let msg = $('#chat-message-input').val();

        if (msg != ''){
            self.socket.emit('send_message', {
                message: msg,
                user_email: self.userEmail,
                chatroom: 'codeial'
            });
        }
    });

    self.socket.on('receive_message', function(data){
        console.log('message received', data.message);


        let newMessage = $('<li>');

        let messageType = 'other-message';

        if (data.user_email == self.userEmail){
            messageType = 'self-message';
        }

        newMessage.append($('<span>', {
            'html': data.message
        }));

        newMessage.append($('<sub>', {
            'html': data.user_email
        }));

        newMessage.addClass(messageType);

        $('#chat-messages-list').append(newMessage);
    })
  }
}
```

expected:connection should be established using sockets..!
  with login user.

Comment: does your node server run behind a reverse proxy like nginx or smth?

Comment: No .right now i have not used nginx

Comment: did you open the custom port of the instance?

Comment: btw if u write your event handlers using arrow functions you can get rid of that `self` variable. i.e. `this.socket.on('connect', () => { this.socket.on('user_joined')....`